# How to use InfoPath forms with PHP

Tags: php, ms-office, infopath, infopath2010

I am looking for a simple way to use microsoft office infopath 2010 forms with php.

Comment: In which way exactly do you want to "use" infopath forms with php? Do you want to process submitted forms Or try to use php with webserver as a sharepoint replacement Or do some xslt transforms? What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to use with webserver as a sharepoint replacement.

Comment: Ok. But in what capacity? Do you want to have a sharepoint alike webservice for submission of forms? Implement sharepoint library components or lists? Unless all you want to do is publish the forms on a webserver (no php needed); you'll need to re-invent a lot of sharepoint code, most of which is not well documented.

Comment: This form is already using in sharepoint. But I need to place it a website (php). Using iframe or such things are not secure and also require authorization. Because, I didn't find to a secure way to place it to website, I thougth it will be better using Infopath form with php in website. I should specify, both forms (on website, and sharepoint) will work with same database but with different db user (in website limited user will be used)